# Java Panel scroll down

Tags: java, swing, button, scroll, panel

I have one button "down" at the end of this panel :

[image]

When I click on it I would like that the offset of the visible part of the panel rise up, like a scroll. after 1/2 second the down button is pressed I can only see the 2nd, 3rd and 4th element, the first is hidden.

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much,

Regards.

Comment: are you meaning collapsible/exandable JPanel(s),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the panel in a JScrollPane without visible scroll bars. Set preferred size of the panel to be bigger (visible height + sum of the buttons' heights). On click down just scroll up according to the next button's height.